# reorder a WP_Query, using a dropdown

Tags: php, wp-query, jquery, order

I have the following loop used to display posts by category & I would like to to re-order them based on a dropdown selector

```
if (!isset($qry))
    $qry = new WP_Query(array('category_name'=>$GLOBALS['city'],'order'=>$orderby));    

if ($qry->have_posts($orderby)) {
    $do_the_post = null;

    if (is_single($orderby)) {
        $do_the_post = true;
    } else {
        $qry->the_post($orderby);
        $do_the_post = false;
    }

    $user = get_userdata($post->post_author);
```

So far, using some code I found [here](http://blog.rutwick.com/use-jquery-to-reorder-your-wp-posts-on-the-fly)

I have:

```
if( isset($_GET['o']) && $_GET['o'] != '')
    {
    $order = $_GET['o'];
    switch($order)
    {
        case 'date-asc': $orderby = 'order=ASC';
            $msg = 'Date Ascending';
            break;
        case 'date-desc': $orderby = 'order=DESC';
        $msg = 'Date Descending(default)';
            break;
        case 'date-mod': $orderby = 'orderby=modified';
            $msg = 'Date Modified';
            break;
        case 'title-asc': $orderby = 'orderby=title&order=ASC';
            $msg = 'Title A-Z';
            break;
        case 'title-desc': $orderby = 'orderby=title&order=DESC';
            $msg = 'Title Z-A';
            break;
        case 'comment': $orderby = 'orderby=comment_count';
            $msg = 'Comment Count';
            break;
    }
    }
    else
    {
        $orderby = 'order=DESC';
        $msg = 'Date Descending (default)';
    }


            <div id="sorter-container">
            <select id="order-by">
                <option value="date-desc" <?php echo (!isset($order) || $order == '' || $order == 'date-desc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Date Desc. (default)</option>
                <option value="date-asc" <?php echo ($order == 'date-asc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Date Asc</option>
                <option value="date-mod" <?php echo ($order == 'date-mod')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Date Modified</option>
                <option value="title-desc" <?php echo ($order == 'title-desc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Title Desc.</option>
                <option value="title-asc" <?php echo ($order == 'title-asc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Title Asc.</option>
                <option value="comment" <?php echo ($order == 'comment')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Comments Count</option>
        </select>
        </div>
```

//JQUERY

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var orderby = jQuery('#order-by');
        var str;
        orderby.change(function(){
        str = jQuery(this).val();
        window.location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/gallery/?o="+str;
    });
    </script>
```

Is calling $orderby as the order is not working - my PHP is rudimentary at best, but can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is

```
$qry = new WP_Query(array('category_name'=>$GLOBALS['city'],'order'=>$orderby));
```

Let's just say **$orderby** is **orderby=title&order=ASC**

Then the order argument of WP_Query will be like this:

```
'order'=>'orderby=title&order=ASC'
```

However, order argument only accepts: [ASC and DESC](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

You should do somethings like this:

```
WP_Query('category_name='.$GLOBALS['city'].'&'.$orderby);
```

Comment: This is great & works, thankyou.

One quick question if you don't mind....

Taking the array out won't make a difference?

Comment: it'll be automatically converted to array by wp_parse_args. yep, WP_Query will use wp_parse_args